# Button text to wrap like inline spans

Tags: css

Is it possible to wrap button text next to a span? So that the button appears over multiple lines.

E.g:

```css
div {
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 150px;
}

button {
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </span><button>Button with a long label</button>
</div>
```

In the case above the button text should continue as though it were part of the text, similar to a link.

Comment: You have transparent backgrund set another background-color and button is correct

Comment: @WalterWhite nothing to do with background colors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`display:contents;` can do this but you may lose more than what you will win (it can break the accessibility as well)

```css
div {
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 150px;
}

button {
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
  display:contents;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </span><button><span>Button with a long label</span></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Great answer! I'd also reccomend adding `font: inherit` so it flows inline like the rest of the text. However, it would also be a good idea to then change the colour or background of the button so we can make it different from  the rest of the text.

Answer (score -1):

Button is always rendered by the browser as inline-block. So what you want is not possible without changing the button tag to something like an href.

Answer (score -2):

Wrap div into container

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: auto;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </span><button>Button with a long label</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This is simply making the div wider to accommodate the length of the button, which is not what I need. And it does not wrap the text of the button inline